# Main method not found in class temperature.Temperature, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, runtime-error

I keep getting this error and don't know what to do. It's frustrating the heck out of me:

> Main method not found in class temperature.Temperature, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Source code:

```
public class Temperature {
    // ... various methods and properties
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temperature iceC = new Temperature();
        Temperature iceF = new Temperature('F');

        // ... etc
    }
}
```

Comment: The `main` method is in the `Test` class, so run it from there or move to the `Temperature`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run class, which have no main() method. 

Also, nobody use Java without IDE. Especially if you're novice. Just install NetBeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, and you'll see all your errors and misprints 'on the fly'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :D. In addition to the previous comment, please consider choosing a more generic, clearer title (like "Error: Main method not found" when executing my code).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to start your program by command line 
with "java Temperature"?

So Java is searching the main method in the class Temperature.

Ways to go:

1. if you move your main method to the Class Temperature
2. if you move your inner class to an extra file and start your program with "java Test"